# Cherrypy routing using inner function

Tags: python, cherrypy

I would like to call to `http://localhost:8080/match/123/subtitle`

```
def match(self, dayid):
    day = dayid
    day_folder = os.path.join(root_folder,day)                      
    #Some logics here

    @cherrypy.expose
    def subtitle(self, mid):
        return "Requesting subtitle for ", mid
```

Is this not the right way? If not, what is the proper way of rewriting Url ?

I tried the following but it doesn't work too.

```
d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect('default_route', '', controller=HelloWorld)
d.connect('subtitle', 'match/{mid}/subtitle', controller=HelloWorld, action='subtitle')

cherrypy.config.update({{'request.dispatch': d}})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a custom dispatcher. This is a simple example to give you an idea. You were on the right track here.

```
import cherrypy

class my_index_controller:
        @cherrypy.expose
        def index(self):
                return """<h1>WORKS</h1>"""


class other_controller:
        @cherrypy.expose
        def subtitle(self, mid):
                return """<h1>WORKS2 %s</h1>""" % str(mid)

controller1 = my_index_controller()
controller2 = other_controller()
d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
d.connect('index', '/', controller=controller1, action='index')
d.connect('subtitle', '/match/:mid/subtitle', controller=controller2, action='subtitle')
conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': d}}

if __name__=='__main__':
        cherrypy.quickstart(controller1, '/', config=conf)
```

Comment: What does the mount do actually?

Comment: You don't need to mount before quickstart.

Comment: Yes, true, no need. Updated.